# Best algorithm to populate the minimum value of rows above in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a data frame i'd like to create a new column titled "min". Which stores the lowest number (found in 'num' column) of the rows above (including current row). Is there a built in API that does this? I can only think of creating a loop that loops through every prior row.

The output for the "min" column should look like the picture below.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `df.num.cummin()`

Comment: Thanks you're fast! Livin up to your name :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided this is your dataframe:(only a sample)

```
In [2249]: df
Out[2249]: 
               date   num
0  12/10/2018 13:56   400
1  12/10/2018 12:28   600
2  12/10/2018 13:57   300
3  12/10/2018 12:36  1200

In [2251]: df['min'] = df['num'].cummin()

In [2252]: df
Out[2252]: 
               date   num  min
0  12/10/2018 13:56   400  400
1  12/10/2018 12:28   600  400
2  12/10/2018 13:57   300  300
3  12/10/2018 12:36  1200  300
```